# Can one dragon's destruction bring back all of my Keepers of the Shrine?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

If there are 3 copies of [Keeper of the Shrine](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Keeper_of_the_Shrine) in the graveyard and a dragon is destroyed, can you summon all three back and get 3 dragons if normal? Or can you only use one a turn?

Answer (score 2):

CDClarke is correct in his [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/40054/22373); you cannot do that what you propose.

To enhance on the reason *why* it is once again important to note that specific part:

> You can only use **this effect** of **"Keeper of the Shrine"** once per turn.

One thing that this specifies is that only *this* effect has restrictions; you can use the *"This card can be treated as 2 Tributes for..."* part as many times as you want/can.

Another relevant thing to notice is that this quote references to the card *in general*. This means that the restriction applies to *any* [Keeper of the Shrine](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Keeper_of_the_Shrine) you have.

You could do what you propose if the card text said instead *"You can only use this effect of **this card** once per turn."* Card texts that you see contain such phrasing or similar refer to that specific *copy* of your card, restricting it from being repeatedly used (however it does not restrict other copies).

It is important to note those two different situations to effectively tell apart from a restriction that applies to a copy from that that applies to the card in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read through the text box of Keeper of the Shrine.

> This card can be treated as 2 Tributes for the Tribute Summon of a Dragon-Type monster. While this card is in your hand or Graveyard, if a face-up Dragon-Type monster on the field, except "Keeper of the Shrine", is sent to the Graveyard by a card effect or because it was destroyed by battle: You can Special Summon this card, then, if that monster sent to the Graveyard is a Normal Monster, you can add 1 Dragon-Type Normal Monster from your Graveyard to your hand. **You can only use this effect of "Keeper of the Shrine" once per turn.**

Pay extra attention to the part I've emphasised at the end. The wording of this clause is known as a 'hard' once per turn, because it specifically restricts you from using the effect of any card with the original name 'Keeper of the Shrine' more than once in a turn. So, unfortunately, you'll only be able to get back one Keeper when a dragon is sent to the graveyard, even though they're separate cards.